# Class Access Modifiers - internal

Tags: c#, class, enums, internal, access-modifiers

I have created a class called `ClientCapsule` which contains data about the client,
this class contains another class i created in the same scope called `ClientInformation` .

i don't want to allow creation of `ClientInformation` class outside of the `ClientCapsule`, yet i want to allow `ClientInformation` instance as a member of `ClientCapsule` and allow access to `ClientInformation` members when creating `ClientCapsule` instance.

here is an example of what i'm trying to do:

```
namespace AdminServer
{
    public enum ClientOperation
    {
        Subscribe,
        GetTables
    }

    [Serializable]
    internal class ClientInformation
    {

    }

    [Serializable]
    public class ClientCapsule
    {


        public readonly IPHostEntry clientMetaData;

        public readonly ClientOperation clientRequestedOperation;

        public readonly ClientInformation clientInfo;
    }
}
```

So i won't be able to do out side of this scope: `ClientInformation object = new ClientInformation()`

BUT i would be able to do: `ClientCapsule object = new ClientCapsule(),object.ClientInformation.members;`

but i'm getting an error:

> Inconsistent accessibility field type `ClientInformation` is less accessible than field `ClientCapsule.clientInfo`

Comment: `ClientInformation` would have to be `public`. You could create it with an `internal` constructor though, if you like. Otherwise you have a class which *is* visible outside of your assembly, yet has members of types which are *not* visible outside the assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need `ClientInformation` to be a public class - just give it an internal constructor, preventing instantiation from elsewhere.

Comment: Alternatively an internal class with a public interface, only exposing the interface publicly.

Comment: @Servy: Yes, although that would invite other implementations which may not be ideal. It could also easily be over-engineering, although it's hard to tell without more context.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have this: `public readonly ClientInformation clientInfo;` in your public class, ClientInformation has to be public. In addition to what the other guy mentioned of having an internal constructor, you can also use an interface instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your `clientinfo` accessibility is `public`, but `clientinfo` is `ClientInformation` type variable and `ClientInformation` accessibility is not `public`.

> So ClientInformation is less accessible than field
>   ClientCapsule.clientInfo